# Search for a string in all table columns in database sql

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

How can i search a value that matches all columns in database in a single query.

Do i need to query like i do , or is there any simple way to implement this?

My code:-

```
SET @SearchString='search_string' 


SELECT   @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),COUNT(*)) + '' matches in   column ''+'''
     + C.name + '''+'' on table '' + ''' + SC.name + '.' + T.name + 
     ''' [Matches for '''+@SearchString+''':] FROM ' + 
     QUOTENAME(SC.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.name) + ' WHERE ' +   QUOTENAME(C.name) + 
     ' LIKE ''%' + @SearchString + 
     '%'' HAVING COUNT(*)>0 UNION ALL ' +CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
FROM     sys.columns C 
JOIN     sys.tables T 
ON       C.object_id=T.object_id 
JOIN     sys.schemas SC 
ON       SC.schema_id=T.schema_id 
JOIN     sys.types ST 
ON       C.user_type_id=ST.user_type_id 
JOIN     sys.types SYST 
ON       ST.system_type_id=SYST.user_type_id 
AND      ST.system_type_id=SYST.system_type_id 
WHERE    SYST.name IN ('varchar','nvarchar','text','ntext','char','nchar') 
ORDER BY T.name, C.name 

IF LEN(@SQL)>12 
SELECT @SQL=LEFT(@SQL,LEN(@SQL)- 12) 

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code,

```
exec SearchAllTables @SearchStr='Your search string';
```

This executes a case insensitive search on all tables in the relevant database, and neatly spits out the fields where the string occurs in.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchAllTables (@SearchStr NVARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Results TABLE (
        ColumnName NVARCHAR(370)
        ,ColumnValue NVARCHAR(3630)
        )

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(256)
        ,@ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)
        ,@SearchStr2 NVARCHAR(110)

    SET @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%', '''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                    AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
                )

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL)
            AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName = (
                    SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                        AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                        AND DATA_TYPE IN (
                            'char'
                            ,'varchar'
                            ,'nchar'
                            ,'nvarchar'
                            )
                        AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
                    )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @Results
                EXEC (
                        'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' + ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                        )
            END
        END
    END

    SELECT ColumnName
        ,ColumnValue
    FROM @Results
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the help..Am just beginner to sql server.Is this stored procedure can directly apply for my need or need to customize it?

Comment: No need to customize. Just run and check the results. I you won't get expected result then let me know.

Comment: I have executed the query, the procedure is created and got output in mssql management studio 2014.Could please tell me how to use this procedure in my php codeigniter query

Comment: I have got the query.once again thanks.A little bit time consuming i think it is normal is it?Is there anyway to increase execution speed?

Comment: how to search for multiple search strings here ?exec SearchAllTables @SearchStr='Your search string';